# Relationship Between "Assignment Problems" and "Graphs"

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-optimization

I was reading the following Wikipedia Article on "Assignment Problems" that talks about the relationship between **Assignment Problems** and **Graph Theory** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) :

- *The assignment problem is a fundamental combinatorial optimization problem. In its most general form, the problem is as follows:*
- *The problem instance has a number of agents and a number of tasks. Any agent can be assigned to perform any task, incurring some cost that may vary depending on the agent-task assignment. It is required to perform as many tasks as possible by assigning at most one agent to each task and at most one task to each agent, in such a way that the total cost of the assignment is minimized.*
- *Alternatively, describing the problem using graph theory:
  The assignment problem consists of finding, in a weighted bipartite graph, a matching of a given size, in which the sum of weights of the edges is minimum.*

I am familiar with both of these concepts individually, but I do not understand why these concepts are related:

**1) Assignment Problems**

Assignment Problems - as the name implies - are usually about determining an "optimal assignment of tasks to agents". For example, suppose there are 4 Workers (Worker A, Worker B, Worker C, Worker D) and 4 Jobs (Job A, Job B, Job C, Job D). Each worker has a "certain cost" associated with performing each of these jobs (e.g. Worker A performs Job B better than Worker D, but Worker D performs Job D better than Worker A). The Assignment Problem involves "assigning" only one job to each worker such that the total cost is minimized:

[image]

**2) Weighted Bipartite Graphs**

A Bipartite Graph is a Graph in which all "Nodes" within the Graph (i.e. circles) either belong to one of two sets (e.g. red and blue). A Weighted Bipartite Graph is a Bipartite Graph in which each "Edge" has a certain cost associated with it:

[image]

**My Question:** The formal definition of a general Assignment Problem is seen below:

[image]

Thus, can someone please explain why "**the assignment problem consists of finding, in a weighted bipartite graph, a matching of a given size, in which the sum of weights of the edges is minimum"** ?

Comment: Let yellow be the agents A, B, C, D. Let blue be the tasks job1, job 2, job 3, job 4. Let the cost of each edge be the corresponding entry of the assignment cost matrix.  Now minimize the cost of the matching. That seems like a pretty good correspondence to me.

Comment: @ Mark L Stone: Thank you for your reply! I can see that the Assignment Problem does correspond to a Weighted Bipartite Graph , and that we want to find the sum of weights of the edges in minimum .... but why do we want to find a "matching"?

Comment: I think this is just a formality that corresponds to the constraint - a "matching" is a graph where each edge is without common vertices.  I guess this is to make sure that a worker can not be assigned more than one job? thank you so much!

Comment: Each node in the yellow should be matched to exactly one node in the blue.  Just as each agent should be assigned (matched) to exactly one task. No agent can be assigned more than one task, and no task can be assigned to more than one agent.